# How to initialize tinymce as plain-text editor

Tags: plaintext, tinymce-5

I want to use the tinymce editor for visualizing special chars like a paragraph like this: ¶
It should only visualize it. The value of the input should contain only plain text.
Is there a setup param to force tinymce to work in plain text mode?

Comment: maybe tinymce isn't the right editor to choose. I will give <a href="https://ace.c9.io/" target="_blank">ace</a> a try. Maybe this editor only visualize the invisible characters but leave the original code untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve content from the TinyMCE editor as HTML or plaintext. To retrieve the content as plaintext specify `format: 'text'` when you get the content. For example:

```
// Get the contents of the currently active editor as plain text
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'text'});
```

For more information about `getContent`, see: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent.

Comment: The ace editor fits my needs even better.
But maybe this could come in handy for another project.